# Height and Width of JQgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two `jqgrids` on my aspx page. I want to set the height of these `jqgrids` in a manner that both of them are visible without Scrolling the whole page.
So the First problem is height of `jqgrids`, here is the screenshot

[Both Jqgrids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOQjF.png)

On a search button's click I want to show the second `jqgrid` only if there is any data found on `loadcomplete` function of `jqgrid` for that search item.This is my `jqgrid` design:

```
     <div  class="row" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
                  <div id="showGridSearchResult" style="display:none">
                        <table id="GrdSearchResult" style="text-align: center;"></table>
                        <div id="GrdSearchResultpagingGrid"></div>
                    </div>  

                </div>
            </div>
```

And on ladcomplete I have done this

```
loadComplete: function (record) {                           
                        if (record.d.records != 0) {
                            $("#imgLoading").hide();
                            $("#showGridSearchResult").show();                               
                            isfirstload = false;
                            isreloadnewdata = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#showGridSearchResult").hide();                                
                            MessageBox("No Records Found!!");
                            $("#divn").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                            $("#imgLoading").hide();

                        }
```

Second problem is when I used `show()` and `hide()` methods for the second `jqgrid` that should only appear when there is data present,gets distorted in width after the use of `show()` and `hide()` methods. Here is the image

[Distorted Jqgrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AusJd.png)

please help with both the issues distortion of grid and height of jqgrid

Answer (score 0):

The height of the grid when set in grid options is the height of the data. With small exceptions the entry grid has a height = height of the data + the height of the pager(if present)  + height of the header row + the height of the caption (if preset)

So when you set the height of the grid you should take into account these height.

To show and hide the grid I recommend you not to use the id of the grid, but of the entire box like

```
$("#gbox_showGridSearchResult).hide();
```

instead of

```
$("#showGridSearchResult").hide();
```

Comment: I am not hiding the id of grid  as "showGridSearchResult"  is the id of the div that contains my div  @ Tony Tomov

Comment: And moreover my problem of show and hide is ok now but the width of grids is still an issue. Every time any new event raises on my screen width of grids increases